# HttpRequestException: Could Not Head warning in Android Studio 3.1.1 (But Sync Successfully)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I facing a problem while syncing the project. I am getting warning after sync successfully
[image: warning messages]

I don't know why I am getting this warning. If click on warning in build window than get this message 
[image: message after sync]

Message in image is

`org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom'`.

**Caused by:**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

If Click on `url`

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom than get this message -

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Could not find resource"
  } ]
}
```

I am using

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

and

```
 implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${support_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${play_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:${play_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${play_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:${play_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${play_version_old}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${play_version_old}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${play_version_old}"
```

```
buildscript{

    ext{
        play_version = '15.0.2'
        play_version_old = '15.0.0'
        support_version = '27.1.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: I answered its solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73739798/2848731 . It may help other who come on this page for solution

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this problem by
File -> Settings -> Tools -> Server Certificates -> Accept non-trusted certificates automatically

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to Internet and if you are connected to Internet then your Internet firewall is forbidding to make connection with `https://jcenter.bintray.com`. Try to sync with different Internet connection.

I had same problem while upgrading `gradle` version in my office Internet but when I tried with by personal Internet connection it went softly.